# Accessing Information of friends of my website user

Tags: facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I have a tough situation here. When a `User A` logs into my website he authorizes me to pull out his information from facebook. Now what I am doing is searching `User A` facebook friends present on my website(suppose I got `User B`)..and then showing User A information of `User B` friends. Now I am getting very limited information of `User B` friends even if User B has authorized our site to pull out information of his friends.

Please give your input.

Answer (score 0):

User B would have to have very open privacy settings for you to get information on them, unless they have also allowed your application. The default settings are pretty relaxed, but I suspect lots of people, like me, disable everything.

[image: Ignore the red circle, that was for another answer along similar lines]

Ignore the red circle, that was for another answer along similar lines.

Comment: I don't understand, all Facebook users have such settings. Are you saying that as in your example, User B has very relaxed settings from the above pane? How could you know that?